# How to identify Cassandra Keyspace, using JanusGraph APIs?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, janus

While going through "https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.5/basics/configuration-reference/" , I found that for key "storage.cassandra.keyspace", "The name of JanusGraph's keyspace. It will be created if it does not exist. If it is not supplied, but graph.graphname is, then the the keyspace will be set to that."

I want to get this configured keyspace at runtime in java code for some validation. Is there any way through which we can identify this configured keyspace?

Also, if we create keyspace through Cassandra CQL command and try to use that in JanusGraph server, server throws exception. This means that JanusGraph can nly recognize keyspace which is created by JanusGraph itself. So, I want to identify that which keyspace is created by JanusGraph and which by Cassandra itself.